# How do I run several Keras neural network models in different files?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, neural-network

So I have three models created in three different files: Model_A.py, Model_B.py, Model_C.py. Model_A is the first one i have created. When I run Model_A, everything works well. However, when I run Models B or C python still runs Model A. I guessed it has to do with the session, but I am not sure and I have not figured out how to fix it.

Here is Code for model A.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import os
import glob
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2' #this removes some warning comments. This warning comments express that this PC has a CPU able to
#compute much faster, and that tensorflow was not designed for it. For the moment, will keep it like this. If necessary, we'll use GPU
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import warnings
from math import sqrt
from keras import backend as K

#Early stopping based on loss
class EarlyStoppingByLossVal(Callback):
    def __init__(self, monitor='val_loss', value=0.00001, verbose=0):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.value = value
        self.verbose = verbose

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        current = logs.get(self.monitor)
        if current is None:
            warnings.warn("Early stopping requires %s available!" % self.monitor, RuntimeWarning)

        if current < self.value:
            if self.verbose > 0:
                print("Epoch %05d: early stopping THR" % epoch)
            self.model.stop_training = True

NAME = "TensBo{}".format(int(time.time()))
tensorboard = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(NAME))

# # DATA MANAGER: Define a function that imports and defines data

def data_manager(paths, col, row_drop, inout):

    # # PREDICTION DATA

    test_files = glob.glob(paths[0] + "/*.csv")  # keeping directories in a list
    n_test = len(test_files)  # number of files
    q = 0
    test = [None]*n_test

    for csv in test_files:
        pred_data = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=';', encoding='cp1252')
        t_step = pred_data.shape[0]  # as all data has the same shape, we can keep these values for later use

        #((1 t_step-1 inout[0]) (batch_sz t_step-1 inout[0]) (batch_sz t_step-1  inout[0]))


        pred_input = np.array(np.reshape(pred_data.drop(columns=col, index=row_drop).values,
                                         (1, t_step-1, inout[0])), dtype='float') #Remove selected columns and indexes. Reshape data
        pred_output = np.array(pred_data.loc['1':, col[1]: col[2]], dtype='float')


        test[q] = [pred_input, pred_output]

        q = q + 1


    # # TRAINING DATA

    #Introduce the path and count files

    train_files = glob.glob(paths[1] + "/*.csv") #keeping directories in a list
    n_files = len(train_files) #number of files


    #To check encoding of a file just print its path: with open(r'I:\05_Basanta Franco\Python\Data02\Data1574095060.csv') as f:
        #print(f)


    inputs = np.zeros([n_files*(t_step-1), inout[0]])
    targets = np.zeros([n_files * (t_step-1), inout[1]])
    i = t_step-1
    j = 0

    #import all the csv in files and store them in data
    for csv in train_files:
        matrix = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=';', encoding='cp1252')
        data_in = matrix.drop(columns=col, index=row_drop).values
        data_out = matrix.loc['1':, col[1]: col[2]].values

        inputs[j:i, :] = data_in
        targets[j:i, :] = data_out
        i = i + t_step-1
        j = j + t_step-1

    batch_sz = n_files


    # creating input an target tensors of size batch, timestep, inputs

    inputs = np.reshape(inputs, (batch_sz, t_step-1, inout[0])) #input selection
    targets = np.reshape(targets, (batch_sz, t_step-1, inout[1])) #target selection

    return test, inputs, targets, n_test, t_step

# # PATHS

test_path = r'I:\05_Basanta Franco\Python\Test'
train_path = r'I:\05_Basanta Franco\Python\Data02'
model_path = r'I:\05_Basanta Franco\Python\model\model01\model{}.h5'

paths = [test_path, train_path, model_path]


# # IMPORT DATA

col = ['All calculations', 'MSNS-Trafo', 'MSNS-Trafo.1']
row_drop = 0
inout = [11, 2]

test, inputs, targets, n_test, t_step = data_manager(paths, col, row_drop, inout) #test is a list with test inputs and outputs.

# # NEURAL NETWORK CREATOR

# Creating a model, which is a linear stack of layers
model = Sequential()

'''
LSTM layer of n nodes. Shape of the input is the columns of inputs. activation function is rectifier linear function.
Return sequencies = true basically tells the layer to output a sequence. If we were to have another Recurrent layer, this is necessary. Else not, as it would not understand it
Time distribute is important. That basically relates every input step in the input sequence with its corresponding output. 
Other way we would just be considering the last value of the sequence
'''

l1 = model.add(layers.LSTM(inout[0], input_shape=(t_step-1, inout[0]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True)) #adding a RNN layer
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(inout[0])))


l3 = model.add(layers.LSTM(30, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)) #adding a RNN layer
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(20)))

l4 = model.add(layers.LSTM(10, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)) #adding a RNN layer
model.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(10)))

model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

l5 = model.add(layers.Dense(2)) #fully connected layer. What i would understand as a normal layer

opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-03) #how fast the learning rate decays. this helps finding the miminum better

callbacks = [EarlyStoppingByLossVal('val_loss', value=0.002),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepath=model_path.format(int(time.time())), save_best_only=True)]
#

#compiling the model. Defining some of the features for the fit like the type of loss function, the optimizer and metrics that are interesting for us
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
             optimizer=opt,
             metrics=['mse', 'mae'])  # accuracy only valid for clasiffication tasks

history = model.fit(inputs, targets, epochs=50, validation_split=0.25, callbacks=callbacks)


# Evaluate the model

scores = model.evaluate(inputs, targets, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))


# print a summary of the outputs of every layer

print(model.summary())

#SAVING THE MODEL

#
#The model is saved by modelcheckpoint in a folder. Here, we are saving the models arquitecture in a json file
#model_json = model.to_json()
#with open("model/model01/model.json", "w") as json_file:
#    json_file.write(model_json)

# PREDICTIONS WITH THE MODEL

t = 1
fig1 = plt.figure()
for prediction in test:

    NN_pred = model.predict(prediction[0])


    #ANALYSIS
    #reshape the prediction for plotting
    NN_pred = np.reshape(NN_pred, (prediction[1].shape[0], inout[1]))
    prediction[0] = np.reshape(prediction[0], (t_step-1, inout[0]))


    #plots: top, predicted and desired test output. down, test inputs

    plt.subplot(n_test, 1, t)
    plt.title('Test0' + np.str(t))
    plt.plot(NN_pred)
    plt.plot(prediction[1])
    plt.legend(['I_real_pred', 'I_im_pred', 'Ir', 'Ii'])


    # mean squared error
    rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(prediction[1], NN_pred))
    print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)

    t = t + 1

fig2 = plt.figure()

# plot loss during training
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title('Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
plt.legend()
# plot mse during training
plt.subplot(212)
plt.title('Mean Squared Error')
plt.plot(history.history['mse'], label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_mse'], label='test')


#  print inputs yes or no
printin = input('Print inputs as well? [y/n]: ')

m = True
while m == True:

    if printin == 'y':

        t = 1
        fig3 = plt.figure()

        for prediction in test:
            plt.title('Inputs: V, P, Q')
            plt.subplot(n_test, 1, t)
            plt.plot(prediction[0])
            t = t + 1
        m = False
    elif printin == 'n':

        m = False
    else:

        printin = input('Answer not valid. Print inputs? [y/n]: ')

plt.show()
```

And here is codel model B.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import os
import glob
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2' #this removes some warning comments. This warning comments express that this PC has a CPU able to
#compute much faster, and that tensorflow was not designed for it. For the moment, will keep it like this. If necessary, we'll use GPU
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers, optimizers
from tensorflow import Graph

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from keras import backend as K
from Model_A import EarlyStoppingByLossVal

K.clear_session()

def data_manager_1(paths, col, row_drop, inout):

    # # PREDICTION DATA

    test_files = glob.glob(paths[0] + "/*.csv")  # keeping directories in a list
    n_test = len(test_files)  # number of files
    q = 0
    test = [None]*n_test

    for csv in test_files:
        pred_data = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=';', encoding='cp1252')
        t_step = pred_data.shape[0]  # as all data has the same shape, we can keep these values for later use


        pred_input = np.array(np.reshape(pred_data.drop(columns=col, index=row_drop).values,
                                         (t_step-1, 1, inout[0])), dtype='float') #Remove selected columns and indexes. Reshape data
        pred_output = np.array(pred_data.loc['1':, col[1]: col[2]], dtype='float')


        test[q] = [pred_input, pred_output]

        q = q + 1


    # # TRAINING DATA

    #Introduce the path and count files

    train_files = glob.glob(paths[1] + "/*.csv") #keeping directories in a list
    n_files = len(train_files) #number of files


    #To check encoding of a file just print its path: with open(r'I:\05_Basanta Franco\Python\Data02\Data1574095060.csv') as f:
        #print(f)


    inputs = np.zeros([n_files*(t_step-1), inout[0]])
    targets = np.zeros([n_files * (t_step-1), inout[1]])
    i = t_step-1
    j = 0

    #import all the csv in files and store them in data
    for csv in train_files:
        matrix = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=';', encoding='cp1252')
        data_in = matrix.drop(columns=col, index=row_drop).values
        data_out = matrix.loc['1':, col[1]: col[2]].values

        inputs[j:i, :] = data_in
        targets[j:i, :] = data_out
        i = i + t_step-1
        j = j + t_step-1

    batch_sz = n_files


    # creating input an target tensors of size batch, timestep, inputs

    inputs = np.reshape(inputs, (inputs.shape[0], 1, inout[0])) #input selection
    targets = np.reshape(targets, (targets.shape[0], 1, inout[1])) #target selection

    return test, inputs, targets, n_test, t_step

# # PATHS

test_path = r'I:\05_Basanta Franco\Python\Test'
train_path = r'I:\05_Basanta Franco\Python\Data02'
model_path = r'I:\05_Basanta Franco\Python\model\model02\model{}.h5'

paths = [test_path, train_path, model_path]

# # IMPORT DATA

col = ['All calculations', 'MSNS-Trafo', 'MSNS-Trafo.1']
row_drop = 0
inout = [11, 2]

test, inputs, targets, n_test, t_step = data_manager_1(paths, col, row_drop, inout) #test is a list with test inputs and outputs.

# # CREATE THE MODEL


model02 = Sequential()

l1 = model02.add(layers.LSTM(inout[0], input_shape=(1, inout[0]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True)) #adding a RNN layer
model02.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(inout[0])))


l3 = model02.add(layers.LSTM(5, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)) #adding a RNN layer
model02.add(layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(5)))

model02.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

l5 = model02.add(layers.Dense(2)) #fully connected layer. What i would understand as a normal layer

#compiling the model. Defining some of the features for the fit like the type of loss function, the optimizer and metrics that are interesting for us

opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-03) #how fast the learning rate decays. this helps finding the miminum better

callbacks = [EarlyStopping('val_loss', patience=20),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepath=model_path.format(int(time.time())), save_best_only=True)]

model02.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
             optimizer=opt,
             metrics=['mse', 'mae'])  # accuracy only valid for clasiffication tasks

# train model and save history

history = model02.fit(inputs, targets, epochs=20, validation_split=0.25, callbacks=callbacks)


# plot loss during training

def train_plots(history):

    fig2 = plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.title('Loss')
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
    plt.legend()
    # plot mse during training
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.title('Mean Squared Error')
    plt.plot(history.history['mse'], label='train')
    plt.plot(history.history['val_mse'], label='test')

    plt.show()

train_plots(history)
```

I tried to initialize graphs and sessions for the creation of the models, but it is not working.

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: what is the end result that you whish?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible(at least as a workaround) to kill each process after it finishes the task? Killing the process would ensure the release of memory of TensorFlow.

If the models need a communication channel/have intermediate results sent over, you could use queues or text files in order to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it. My problem was that I was unable to reset the tensorflow session or clean the Graphs in my session to create and train a different model. I found that the command `keras.backend.reset_uids()` does that. Thank you anyway!